# Spectrum homeomorphic to $S^1$

Tags: general-topology

Consider 
$$A=\mathbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2-1),$$
the quotient of the ring of polynomials in two variables, modulo the ideal generated by $f=X^2+Y^2-1$ of, equivalently, the ring of remainders modulo $f$.  Interpret it as an algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ and show that $X_A$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

I already figured the following:

$\hat{t}^2+\hat{s}^2=\hat{1}$, so $\widehat{t^2+s^2}=\hat{1}$ if and only if $t^2+s^2-1$ is divisible by $t^2+s^2-1$. Also, any $\chi$ is determined by $u:=\chi(\hat{t}), v:=\chi(\hat{s})$ and one must have $u^2+v^2=1$. 
This is equivalent with the fact that any character gives you a point on the circle.

Now we know that there is a bijection between $X_A$ and $S^1$, with $\chi\mapsto(\chi(\hat{t}),\chi(\hat{s}))$ continuous. 
Left to prove is that $X_A\rightarrow S^1, (u,v)\mapsto \chi_{u,v}$ is continuous.

How do I prove this?

Comment: What is $X_A$ here?

Comment: @BalarkaSen $X_A$ is uniquely determined by $(\chi(\hat{t}),\chi(\hat{s}))$

Comment: @BalarkaSen how could this help me to complete the answer?